Does Analysis Services provide connection pooling
We know that when creating a SQL connection, for example:
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString));

we are actually not always creating a new connection to the server, but rather we are taking an already open connection from the connection pool.

However, when we open a connection to the Analysis Services, do we also use some kind of connection pooling?
using (AdomdConnection adomdConn = new AdomdConnection(conString));

Does this always lead to a new connection or does it take one from the pool if possible?
I am not able to infer this from the official documentation, but I have found mostly older unofficial articles that clearly state there is no connection pooling for AdomdConnection:

SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services’s ADOMD.NET Connection Pooling, or Lack Thereof
ADOMD.NET Connection Pooling


using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

public class AdomdConnectionPool
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<AdomdConnection> _connectionPool = new ConcurrentBag<AdomdConnection>();
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public AdomdConnectionPool(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public AdomdConnection GetConnection()
    {
        if (_connectionPool.TryTake(out var connection))
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                return connection;
            }

            // Reopen if the connection is closed
            connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }

        // Create a new connection if the pool is empty
        var newConnection = new AdomdConnection(_connectionString);
        newConnection.Open();
        return newConnection;
    }

    public void ReturnConnection(AdomdConnection connection)
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _connectionPool.Add(connection);
        }
        else
        {
            connection?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

// Usage
var pool = new AdomdConnectionPool("your-connection-string");

using (var conn = pool.GetConnection())
{
    // Use the connection
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Measures].[Sales] ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]";
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
    }

    pool.ReturnConnection(conn);
}

